# Android while getting HTTP response to file how to know it wasn't fully loaded?

Tags: java, android, file, http

I'm using this approach to store a big-sized response from server to parse it later (in AsyncTask):

```
final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
final HttpGet mHttpGetRequest = new HttpGet(strUrl);
mHttpGetRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    final HttpResponse response = client.execute(mHttpGetRequest);
    final StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    lastHttpErrorCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
    lastHttpErrorMsg = statusLine.getReasonPhrase();
    if (lastHttpErrorCode == 200) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        fos = new FileOutputStream(reponseFile);
        entity.writeTo(fos);
        entity.consumeContent();
        fos.flush();
    }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    lastHttpErrorMsg = e.toString();
    return null;
}
catch (final ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    lastHttpErrorMsg = e.toString();
    return null;
}
catch (final UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    lastHttpErrorMsg = e.toString();
    return null;    
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    lastHttpErrorMsg = e.toString();
} finally{
    if (fos!=null)
        try{
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e){}
}
```

now how could I ensure the response was completely received and thus saved to file?
 Assume client's device lost Internet connection while the code was wring response to a file. So the app received only some part of real response and wrote it the file without any err/exception. Its just like stream is finished/closed and AsyncTask fired onPostExecute() cuz job is done - response written to the file. But the point is - response wasn't received completely. And I'm pretty sure it happens cuz I got parsing exceptions like "tag not closed", "unexpected end of file" etc. So I need to detect somehow this situation to prevent code from parsing partial response but can't see how. Since its not about file downloading I cant request its size. So can't know the response's size before receiving it.
 Is it possible to detect such situation at all and how to do it? Or has it has to raise IOException in such cases?

Comment: Are you calling this on an AsyncTask?  If you are then set a Boolean on the onPostExecute.

Comment: Yes its AsyncTask. Which boolean and where to place it and what should it indicate? Its not about did AsyncTask finished the job or not. Its about completing HTTP-response receiving. In any case the AsyncTask gonna fire onPostExecute.

Comment: What about sending a checksum of the payload before you send the payload? that way you can easily check the integrity of the response

Comment: Show the code for the asynctask once you do that I can edit it.

Comment: @YankeeWhiskey - there is no way I can change the server side :)

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to get the stream and parse it?

```
InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(path); 
String path = "file.txt";
int bufferSize = 1024;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
int len = 0;
while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
```

In this way you get the stream sequentially. I don't think there are toher ways to do this.

Try and let me know. :)

Comment: Like I had mentioned above the response is too big. If I'll try to use this approach (like I did before) I will definitely get an OutOfMemory Exception. Its the real reason why I need to store HTTP response to file.

Comment: Got it. Edited! Can you try? : )

Comment: No, you didnt :) Or I didn't get the idea. Its not about reading incomplete response nor reading the file with it. Its about how to determine that I didn't receive the whole response.

Comment: Seems really strange.. is it possible to have the URL to try or see it? Or if it's a json/txt/whatever the file. : /

Comment: The thing is if device uses the 3G or any other type of mobile connection to the Internet incomplete response could be received without any timed out exception. Due to the way such connections works. It could rapidly change the provider, like from EGDE to GPRS and then back. There is no network connection loss happens but HTTP session breaks. Since connection breaks the whole system "thinks" that response was completely received. And that's the problem.

Comment: This seems really weird to me. Btw you didn't answer my question : )

Comment: No I can't provide you the URL. But there is nothing strange with it. Is just responds with big JSON-string.

Answer (score 0):

This seems weird since it should throws timeout response code if you are connecting and disconnected. But with your current case, what I think the best you can do is adding try-catch to the open file code, and if there is exception, bring a pop up says download file incomplete or something, remove that file and ask user to try again. (Sorry I don't have enough reputation to reply)

Comment: not really. The thing is if device uses the 3G or any other type of mobile connection to the Internet that could happen without any timed out exception. Due to the way such connections works. It could rapidly change the provider, like from EGDE to GPRS and then back. There is no connection loss but HTTP session breaks. Since connection breaks the whole system "thinks" that response was completely received. I already did wrap parsing code in try/catch.

Answer (score -2):

try to use `onFinsh();` save to file